# SQL Calculate SUM of a column for a date range by type and order date

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, common-table-expression

I have a table with order date, type of order and paymentamount

| OrderDateTime | Type | PaymentAmount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-02-05 | Delivery | 500 |
| 2021-02-05 | Online | 2000 |
| 2021-02-05 | Online | 1000 |
| 2021-02-06 | Online | 1500 |
| 2021-02-06 | Delivery | 200 |
| 2021-02-06 | Delivery | 900 |
| 2021-02-07 | Online | 2500 |
| 2021-02-08 | Delivery | 500 |

I have a date range with startdate as 2021-02-01 and Enddate as 2021-02-30

I am trying to create a stored proc to calculate SUM(PaymentAmount) by Type for the date range if it matches the order date to get below result

| RevenueDate | Delivery | Online |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-02-01 | $0 | $0 |
| 2021-02-02 | $0 | $0 |
| 2021-02-03 | $0 | $0 |
| 2021-02-04 | $0 | $0 |
| 2021-02-05 | $500 | $3000 |
| 2021-02-06 | $900 | $1500 |
| 2021-02-07 | $0 | $2500 |
| 2021-02-08 | $500 | $0 |
| 2021-02-09 | $0 | $0 |

```
......
```

| 2021-02-30  |    $200      | $0     |

```
Declare @StartDate DATETIME2 ='2021-02-01'
Declare @EndDate DATETIME2 ='2021-02-30'

;WITH Dates(RevenueDate) AS 
    (
        SELECT CAST(@StartDate as Date) as day
        UNION ALL
        SELECT CAST(DATEADD(day, 1, RevenueDate) as Date) as day
        FROM Dates
        WHERE CAST(DATEADD(day, 1, RevenueDate) as Date) <= @EndDate
    ),
CTE_Revenue AS
    (
    
    SELECT 
         Type
        , OrderDateTime             
        , CASE
                WHEN Type = 'Delivery' THEN SUM(PaymentAmount)
                WHEN Type = 'Online'  THEN SUM(PaymentAmount) 
                ELSE 0
          END                                                   AS  Revenue     
        FROM OrderInfo      
        WHERE               
                Type = 'Delivery' OR Type ='Online'             
                AND [P].[DeletedFlag] = 0
        GROUP BY                
                 Type               
                , OrderDateTime                         
        )

        SELECT * FROM Dates LD 
        LEFT JOIN CTE_Revenue CS ON FORMAT(LD.RevenueDate, 'MM/dd/yyyy') = CS.OrderDateTime
        ORDER BY CONVERT(DATE, [RevenueDate]) ASC
        OPTION (maxrecursion 0)
```

I am getting below result

```
| RevenueDate | Delivery     | Online |
|:----        |:------:      | -----: |
| 2021-02-01  |    NULL      | NULL   |
| 2021-02-02  |    NULL      | NULL   |
| 2021-02-03  |    NULL      | NULL   |
| 2021-02-04  |    NULL      | NULL   |
| 2021-02-05  |    $500      | $0     |
| 2021-02-05  |    $0        | $3000  |
| 2021-02-06  |    $900      | $0     |
| 2021-02-06  |    $0        | $1500  |
| 2021-02-07  |    $0        | $2500  |
| 2021-02-08  |    $500      | $0     |
```

.....       ........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use COALAESCE to give NULL value another value

```
CREATE TABLE tab1
    ([OrderDateTime] DATETIME, [Type] varchar(8), [PaymentAmount] int)
;
    
INSERT INTO tab1
    ([OrderDateTime], [Type], [PaymentAmount])
VALUES
    ('2021-02-05 00:00:00.000', 'Delivery', 500),
    ('2021-02-05 00:00:00.000', 'Online', 2000),
    ('2021-02-05 00:00:00.000', 'Online', 1000),
    ('2021-02-06 00:00:00.000', 'Online', 1500),
    ('2021-02-06 10:08:00.000', 'Delivery', 200),
    ('2021-02-06 01:00:00.000', 'Delivery', 900),
    ('2021-02-07 00:00:00.000', 'Online', 2500),
    ('2021-02-08 00:00:00.000', 'Delivery', 500)
;
```

```
8 rows affected
```

```
Declare @StartDate DATETIME2 ='2021-02-01';
Declare @EndDate DATETIME2 = '2021-02-28';
with Extract_Dates_CTE (MyDate) as (
    select CAST(@StartDate as Date)
    Union ALL
    select DATEADD(day, 1, MyDate)
    from Extract_Dates_CTE
    where MyDate < @EndDate
), CTEAMOUNT as(
  SELECT
   CONVERT(date,[OrderDateTime]) as OrderDateTime
  , SUM(CASE WHEN [Type] = 'Delivery' then [PaymentAmount] END)  Delivery
  , SUM(CASE WHEN [Type] = 'Online' then [PaymentAmount] END)  Online
  FROM tab1
  GROUP BY CONVERT(date,[OrderDateTime])
)
  
SELECT ed.MyDate,COALESCE(Delivery,0) Delivery,COALESCE(Online,0) Online
FROM Extract_Dates_CTE ed  LEFT JOIN CTEAMOUNT c_a ON CONVERT(DATE, c_a.[OrderDateTime]) = CONVERT(DATE, ed.MyDate)
ORDER BY ed.MyDate ASC
```

| MyDate | Delivery | Online |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-02-01 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-02-02 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-02-03 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-02-04 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-02-05 | 500 | 3000 |
| 2021-02-06 | 1100 | 1500 |
| 2021-02-07 | 0 | 2500 |
| 2021-02-08 | 500 | 0 |
| 2021-02-09 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-02-10 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-02-11 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-02-12 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-02-13 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-02-14 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-02-15 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-02-16 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-02-17 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-02-18 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-02-19 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-02-20 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-02-21 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-02-22 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-02-23 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-02-24 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-02-25 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-02-26 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-02-27 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-02-28 | 0 | 0 |

```
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/woAO1VA4)

Comment: Thanks @nbk, it is working fine if the column has only dates, if the date column has both date and time and compare we seem to get data as 0 for Delivery. eventhough we convert datetime to date and compare we still get value as 0 CONVERT(DATE, c_a.[OrderDateTime]) = CONVERT(DATE, ed.MyDate) Eg: 2021-02-06 10:08:00.000 for Delivery and another record with same date with different time 2021-02-06 11:08:00.000

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/aEr14_PG - added date and time both and comparing gives duplicate records for the same date

Comment: you need to convert to date and so remove all times from the data, see the changed answer